# What is the best way to implement paging for API backend?

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, paging

I'm creating a search feature that will use the search term to fetch some data from an API call and return the data. Many paging tutorials I looked at do the paging on the server side so it only returns what it needs from the database, but I don't have that option since everything is returned as JSON in one heap.

Is it best to use MVC, populate all the models, pass them to the view, then page from there?
Is it better to use something like AJAX and angular and skip MVC all together?
Or another option entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to get all the data at once? That's hugely inefficient and basically negates the entire point of paging. If the client has already been forced to download all that, then you might as well just show them everything.

Depending on whether or not you control the API, you have various options. If you do control the API, then you should build paging into it. You can send it a page number and amount of items to return, and then the API can response with the total number of items and or how many pages exist, along with the results for just that one page. With this info, you can build a paging system client-side that can keep querying the API a page at a time.

If you don't control the API, then there's likely still some sort of ability to page built-in. Most API providers *want* you to page, so you don't hammer their servers requesting a ton of data that may never be utilized. All of the big APIs (Facebook, Twitter, etc.) support some sort of ability to "page" the results.

Comment: I know it is highly inefficient, but I don't have a choice in the matter. We need paging so we don't have a single page that is forever scrolling. The api as it is will take a parameter like name and return a JSON file with all of the results with that name parameter. Doesn't have the option to be able to pass in something like pages in. It sucks, but I guess i just have to accept my reality

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what API it is but I would check the documentation.

No serious API is going to return you all the data in one go and they all offer a way to specify how many records you can get up to a certain set limit.

I'd have a look at their documentation. If we are talking about an internal API then have a chat with whoever develops it and see what's going on.

Everything depends of course on the size of the data so sometimes it might be ok to send it all in one go if it's not that much to begin with.

Some more details would help clarify things.